# Can I connect to a WebApp other than Youtube TV using Cobalt's websocket?

Tags: cobalt

- Is websocket currently implemented in Cobalt (11.107787)?
- Can I connect to a WebApp other than Youtube TV using Cobalt's websocket?
- What should I do test if possible?

Comment: This is not a coding question, please refer to cobalt-dev@googlegroups.com for Cobalt feature discussions and to your YouTube account manager for questions about certification.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes Cobalt has supported WebSocket since Cobalt 9.
- You can connect to other pages with WebSocket.
- WebSockets in Cobalt were tested with http://autobahn.ws/reports/clients/ (protocol) and https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/tree/master/websockets (WebAPI). And there are nplb test cases.